# Elasticsearch PHP - Exact Word Matches Before Partial Matches

Tags: php, elasticsearch

So I'm trying to sort my search results to show the exact matches before all the partial matches.  What I mean by this is if I have the documents with names:

Set 4/102

Set 44/102

Set 94/102

I'm searching on the term 4/102 and it returns all documents.  This is fine, however, I want the Set 4/102 to show up first but it seemingly sorts them randomly.  Is there a way to use script sorting or something like that to have the exact term match to show up first?

These are my mappings and settings:

```
    $settingsParams = [
        'index' => 'products',
        'body' => [
            'settings' => [
                'analysis' => [
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'substring_analyzer' => [
                            'tokenizer' => 'substring_tokenizer',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase'
                            ]
                        ],
                        'fullword_analyzer' => [
                            'tokenizer' => 'whitespace',
                            'filter' => [
                                'lowercase'
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    'tokenizer' => [
                        'substring_tokenizer' => [
                            'type' => 'nGram',
                            'min_gram' => 3,
                            'max_gram' => 12,
                            'token_chars' => [
                                'letter',
                                'digit',
                                'symbol',
                                'custom'
                            ],
                            'custom_token_chars' => '/'
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
                'max_ngram_diff' => 20
            ]
        ]
    ];

    $mappingParams = [
        'index' => 'products',
        'body' => [
            '_source' => [
                'enabled' => true
            ],
            'properties' => [
                'name' => [
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'fields' => [
                        'keyword' => [
                            'type' => 'keyword'
                        ]
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => 'substring_analyzer',
                    'search_analyzer' => 'fullword_analyzer'
                ],
                'min_price' => [
                    'type' => 'double'
                ],
                'saleprice' => [
                    'type' => 'double'
                ],
                'list_price' => [
                    'type' => 'double'
                ],
                'root_category_rank' => [
                    'type' => 'integer'
                ],
                'interest_level' => [
                    'type' => 'integer'
                ],
                'root_categoryid' => [
                    'type' => 'integer'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "substring_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "substring_tokenizer"
        },
        "fullword_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "substring_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 3,
          "max_gram": 12,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "custom",
            "symbol"
          ],
          "custom_token_chars": "/"
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 50
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "substring_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "fullword_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "4/102"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

The document `"name": "4/102"` is having a higher score as compared to other documents

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66232066",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15275992,
        "_source": {
          "name": "4/102"              // note this
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66232066",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.12562492,
        "_source": {
          "name": "44/102"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66232066",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.12562492,
        "_source": {
          "name": "94/102"
        }
      }
    ]
```